# What is the best way to setup google analytics with blocked internal and localhost traffic in G4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

could anyone help me with setup of google analytics G4 for multi language website in G4 with excluding known networks(office,etc) and local-host. I have tried building in G4 but the result were not expected one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just add a trigger to your configuration Tag, excluding the urls you do not want to track
[image]

and then

[image]

finally do not forget to submit the changes.